# PHP compare two string with one character different in both, wildcard approach

Tags: php, wildcard, string-comparison

need to compare two strings to get a PAIR with only condition that only 5th character must be different ... in mysql it can be achieved by INBXOLC800Y = INBX_LC800Y (using the '_' wildcard) but how to do this in PHP... here is my code uptill now but i guess there might be a more smarter and/or shortest way ???

```
$first_sku_full  = "INBXOLC800Y"; // with O
$second_sku_full = "INBXTLC800Y"; // with T

$first_sku_first_part= substr($first_sku_full,0,4); //gives first 4 characters INBX
$second_sku_first_part= substr($second_sku_full,0,4); //gives first 4 characters INBX

if($first_sku_first_part == $second_sku_first_part){  // matching first 4 characters

    $first_sku_last_part= substr($first_sku_full, 5);   // gives 6th onward characters i.e, LC800Y
    $second_sku_last_part= substr($second_sku_full, 5); // gives 6th onward characters i.e, LC800Y
    if ( $first_sku_last_part == $second_sku_last_part ) { // matching 6th and onward characters
        if ( $first_sku_full != $second_sku_full ) { // matching full strings
            echo "first and second sku is a pair <br/>";
        }else{
            echo "NOT a pair , both SKUs are same <br/>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "NOT a pair , last part of string not matched $first_sku_last_part vs $second_sku_last_part <br/>";
    }
}else{
    echo "NOT a pair , first part of string not matched $first_sku_first_part vs $second_sku_first_part<br/>";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function isOnlyThe5thCharacterDifferent($inp1,$inp2)
{
    if ($inp1[4]!=$inp2[4])
    {
        $inp1[4]=$inp2[4];

        return ($inp1==$inp2);
    }

    return false;
}
```

see it in action: https://3v4l.org/fn2sG

Comment: i'll upvote, the logic is Ok, let the downvoters comment

Answer (score 2):

"with only condition that only 5th character must be different"

```
$first_sku_full  = "INBXOLC800Y"; // with O
$second_sku_full = "INBXTLC800Y"; 

if($first_sku_full[4] != $second_sku_full[4]) {
   //fifth character is different in case above it will return true because O != T
}
```

This way you can check if fifth character is different. You can access string letters with array operator in PHP.

If you want compare rest of string without 5 character you can do it as below

```
$first_sku_full  = "INBXOLC800Y"; // with O
$second_sku_full = "INBXTLC800Y"; 

$first_sku_full[4] = $second_sku_full[4] = '';

if($first_sku_full == $second_sku_full) {
    //the strings are same despite 5th character
}
```

Comment: this does not satisfy *with only condition that **only** 5th character **must** be different*

Comment: both codes are wrong. you need to merge them to produce correct result

Answer (score 1):

Replace the part 5th character with a constant string

```
$first_sku_full_masked = substr_replace($first_sku_full, '#', 4, 1);
$second_sku_full_masked = substr_replace($second_sku_full, '#', 4, 1);
```

and then compare.

That gives

```
INBX#LC800Y
INBX#LC800Y
```

which will be considered as equal. So the condition would be

```
$first_sku_full_masked==$second_sku_full_masked && $first_sku_full!=$second_sku_full
```

Comment: Correct approach, but you can just use $var[4] = '#'; instead of substr_replace().

Comment: this does not satisfy *with only condition that only 5th character **must** be different*

Comment: @sharky for the sake of completeness, I added the condition.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can configure easily **N** positions that must be not equal

```
<?php
    $first_sku_full  = "INBXPLC800YF"; // with O
    $second_sku_full = "INBXTLC800YD"; // with T

    var_dump(isEqual($first_sku_full, $second_sku_full, array(4, 11)));
    /**
      * @param1 string $str1
      * @param1 string $str2
      * @param1 array  $pos
      * @return boolean
      */
    function isEqual($str1, $str2, $pos) {
        if       (strlen($str1) != strlen($str2))                return FALSE;

        for ($i=0 ; $i< strlen($str1) ; $i++) {
            if   ( in_array($i, $pos) && $str1[$i] == $str2[$i]) return FALSE;
            if   (!in_array($i, $pos) && $str1[$i] != $str2[$i]) return FALSE; 
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: @syck thank you for your previous comment, i was completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here you can define your custom wildcard or combine it with the solution from
"Halayem Anis" to define more than one wildcards

```
// just an example array
$arrayToCheck = array(
    "INBXOLC800Y",
    "INBXOLC809Y",
    "INBXTLC800Y",
    "INBXALC800Y",
);

function compareWithWildcard( $stringToCompare, $compareWith, $wildcard = "_" ) {
    if( !$wildcard ) return ( $stringToCompare == $compareWith );

    $wildcardIndex = strpos( $compareWith, $wildcard );

    if( $wildcardIndex !== false ) {
        $stringToCompare[$wildcardIndex] = $wildcard;
    }

    return ( $stringToCompare == $compareWith );
}

$compareTo = "INBX_LC800Y";

var_dump( compareWithWildcard( $arrayToCheck[0], $compareTo ) );
```